# How to know when Composition animation 'ScalarKeyFrameAnimation' (or similar) finished

Tags: c#, .net, animation, uwp, composition

I need to know when `Composition` animation like `ScalarKeyFrameAnimation` finished. How to do this? I've made a call like following:

```
    public void Start()
    {
        if (!IsLoaded) return;
        //SET TARGET PROPERTY - OPACITY
        TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.Target = "Opacity";

        //SET FROM OPACITY
        if (From < 0) this.Opacity = 0;
        else if (From > 1) this.Opacity = 1;
        else this.Opacity = From;

        //SET FINAL VALUE (OPACITY) 
        if (To < 0) TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, 0);
        else if (To > 1) TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, 1);
        else TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, (float)To);

        //SET DURATION
        if (Duration.TotalMilliseconds > 0) TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.Duration = Duration;
        else TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        //SET DELAY
        if (Delay.TotalMilliseconds > 0) TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.DelayTime = Delay;
        else TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation.DelayTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);

        //START
        this.StartAnimation(TargetScalarKeyFrameAnimation);
    }
```

But how to get notification animation has been finished? It will helps lot to synchronise UI and other animation. `StoryboardAnimation` has an event for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to know when Composition animation 'ScalarKeyFrameAnimation' (or similar) finished

Currently, there is no such event that could detect animation finished for composition Api. For your scenario, you could make a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) ans set `Interval` same as animation duration, and call  `StartAnimation` and timer [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.start#Windows_UI_Xaml_DispatcherTimer_Start) at same time. Then could detect animation finished in timer [`Tick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick) event.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually something like this I use just now. So, this means I don't need to make any changes to my code, just waiting if MS add an event later.